# ms acess recordset to populate form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to populate a form with records from a query.  With this code it populates the last record only.  The query is joining lots of tables and it not updateable. (I left out the query as it is long and not the issue)  I want to load the records into the form and allow the user to update.

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim strSQL As String
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim siteno As String
Set dbs = CurrentDb

strsql = "query that works"
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
siteno = "ABCD"

With rst
    Do While Not rst.EOF
        On Error Resume Next 
        Me.SITE_NO = rst.Fields("SITE_NO")
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
End With

Set rst = Nothing
Set dbs= Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: It makes no sense. You loop a recordset while for each record setting a control on the form, thus this will hold the value of the last record. If you wish the form to display the records of the query, just bind the form to the query and delete all this code.

Comment: If the query is not updateable, the form is not updateable. What?

Comment: And show the query, maybe it can be made updateable.